# Geotext detecting countries in some cases, not detecting the same country in a different case

Tags: python, geotext

Im trying to extract all the countries in a string using Geotext

It works fine for a few sentences but doesnt work for some.

Ive tried to do it in Python 3.6.

```
s="India Vs Ireland T20 Series"
s=GeoText(s)
s.countries
```

Expected Results:

```
['India','Ireland']
```

Actual Result:

```
['Ireland']
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use pycountry for your task (it also works with python 3):

**pip install pycountry**

```
import pycountry
text = "United States (New York), United Kingdom (London)"
for country in pycountry.countries:
    # Handle both the cases(Uppercase/Lowercase)
    if str(country.name).lower() in str(text).lower():
        print country.name
```

Comment: Alright. Ill try this. but do you know why geotext is so inconsistent?
I mean when i try the same approach on a different string 

for eg

s='India is my country"
st=GeoText(s)
st.countries

it returns
['India']

Comment: The regex geotext is using to parse your string depends heavily on capitalization.  The 'candidate' strings it tries to match with known location names from your string are "India Vs", "Ireland", and "Series", because it thinks the "Vs" might be part of the location name", and isn't smart enough to try just "Ireland".